# How to generate HTML file with Aptana and ScriptDoc

Tags: javascript, aptana

I'm new to Aptana and want to use build-in ScriptDoc for javascript documentation.
Is ScriptDoc always enabled?
Can I create a HTML documentation of my Code?

Is there another way?

I searched several hours, sorry if it is easy.

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.  See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures